# is udp or tcp neighbour connection encrypted?

Tags: udp, tcp

IS "udp" or "tcp" neighbour  connection encrypted? 
to prevent sniffers to find out which ip have an iota node behind it.

Comment: TCP and UDP are only transport protocols. applications must use additional levels of security for secure data transmission. Or encrypt the data before sending.

Comment: Hi wonkytonky. The question and your comments all don't fit together properly. Are you concerned about sniffers getting the neighbor IPs or about securing the connection with encryption to keep the content private?